# MYSQL sort the next row with the UploadDate when Wilson score interval are equal

Tags: php, mysql, rating, rating-system

I'm working on my photo gallery and I have a filter to sort my media with a Wilson score interval. This score is saved in a field of my table called `score`

For this query I use the following fields : `id`, `UploadTime`, `score`

The issue I am having is that some scores will be exactly the same if lets say if mulitple picture have only one thumb up. In that case I would like to sort the media by the UploadDate field, make the older picture less relevant.

This is my script to sort out all my picture (keep in mind that the score must me higher than 0 to get in the list)

```sql
SELECT *
FROM photos
WHERE   status = 0 
    AND score > 0 
ORDER BY score DESC, id DESC
```

Then for getting the next picture (the next picture is a picture with a lower score or if score is equal output the latest one uploaded). And the $id is the unique id of the current picture

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     photos p
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT score, id
    FROM photos
    WHERE id = ".$id."
    ) p2 ON p.score < p2.score

WHERE p.status = 0 AND p.net_votes > 0
ORDER BY p.score DESC, p.UploadTime DESC
LIMIT    1
```

I have used up all my ideas on how to do this.

Comment: won't the next picture just be the 2-nd row from the first query ?

Comment: Yes, but I have no idea how I can use the first query to get this.

Comment: I think I've almost solved this, but what would happen if scores are the same and times are the same?

Comment: Well the ods of that happening are close to zero. The site will be relatively small and maybe get 50-100 pictures a day. So I don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirly sure (I might have gotten a `>` instead of `<` somewhere). Hopefully this will work

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   photos
WHERE  status = 0
       AND net_votes > 0
       AND ( score < (SELECT p1.score
                      FROM   photos p1
                      WHERE  p1.id = :id)
              OR uploadtime < (SELECT p2.uploadtime
                                  FROM   photos p2
                                  WHERE  p2.id = :id) )
ORDER  BY score DESC,
          uploadtime DESC
LIMIT  1
```

Comment: @JorisBlanc, just keep in mind that I'm not an expert and there's gotta be a better way to do it. Anyway, good luck with your project.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure that there is better way of doing it. But I will optimize my website once everything works.
Thanks

Comment: um... if you need the 2-nd row from a query why not just use LIMIT 1,1

Comment: @Vatev, what you're suggesting is valid in some cases. But let's say you're viewing picture #24 and you want to know what's the next picture, how would you do that?

Comment: It seems i have misunderstood the question.